# Spring: How to programmatically define FactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I want to programmatically setup a FactoryBean on an existing ApplicationContext.
There are a lot of examples on how to define a bean programmatically (e.g.: http://www.carlobonamico.com/blog/2008/01/22/how-to-dynamicallyprogrammatically-define-spring-beans/), but they do not work when I try to define a factory bean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you provided with the link given is exactly the way to go. For a `BeanFactoryPostProcesser` there is no difference between a class implementing `FactoryBean` or one that doesn't. All you typically do is register a `BeanDefinition` via `BeanDefinitionRegistry`.